# Functions not available in a php-file called by Ajax

Tags: php, ajax

In my index.php I include a php-file that has all my functions:

```
<?php require_once('functions.php'); ?>
```

On the same page I do an ajax-call with jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "ajax.php",
           data: {
               search: name
           },
           success: function(html) {
               // do something
           }
       });
```

Inside ajax.php is a function that is defined in functions.php, but **this function is unknown (Error: call to undefined function ...)**

Why are the functions in functions.php not accessible inside ajax.php and how do I make them accessible?

Comment: because you have not included functions.php inside ajax.php or the path of functions.php is wrong

Comment: What is ajax.php? please show full code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only seemed to included the functions in the index.php, not on your ajax.php.

add `<?php require_once('functions.php'); ?>` to your ajax.php.

Answer (score -2):

Add 
`<?php require 'functions.php';?>` to your **ajax.php** file.

Comment: Yes, please use curly quotes in raw code. /sarcasm ;)